# How to get image and pose streams at maximum rate with librealsense using ROS2?

Tags: ubuntu, ros2, realsense

Camera Model T265

Firmware Version 0.2.0.951

OS Linux Ubuntu 20.04LTS

Kernel Version 4.9.253

Platform NVIDIA Jetson

SDK Version 2.53.1

Languace C++

Segment Robot

We are using ROS2 to get streams from librealsense and publish them on topics. We tried to make two different nodes with a pipeline each (one from images and one for pose) and they work at the maximum frame rate but not simultaneously (we get No Device Connected Error on one of the nodes). If we use a single node and a single pipeline for both streams we get all the data but the rate is limited to ~60Hz. We have working C++ code at maximum rate with the callback function but this feature doesn't work under ROS2. How can we get both image and pose streams at maximum rate (200Hz for the pose and 30Hz for the images)?